# Add glibc / libintl.h to Android NDK project

Tags: android, android-ndk

I want to use [a C++ library](https://github.com/libpinyin/libpinyin) in my Android application. It requires `libintl.h` provided by glibc. However, in NDK, it cannot be found.

How could I add glibc support to my Android project?

Answer (score 1):

> How could I add glibc support to my Android project?

You don't. Android uses bionic, not glibc, and the two are not compatible.

As bionic does not currently support libintl.h, you will need to avoid using those APIs when building for Android.